# dynamic class method call chaining by array values

Tags: php

For example I have class **MyClass**:

```
Class MyClass {

    public function method_1() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function method_2() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function method_n() {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And I have array of functions and their arguments:

```
$array = array(
    'method_1' => array(
        '0' => 'first_argument',
        '1' => 'second_argument',
        '2' => 'nth_argument',
    ),
    'method_2' => array(
        '0' => 'first_argument',
        '1' => 'second_argument',
        '2' => 'nth_argument',
    ),
);
```

How to call `MyClass` methods from the array in chain?

```
$result = $my_class->$array['method_1']($array['method_1'][0], $array['method_1'][0])
    ->$array['method_1']($array['method_2'][0], $array['method_2'][0])
    ->$array['method_n']($array['method_n'][0], $array['method_n'][0]);
```

For example:

```
foreach($array as $function => $args) {
   // build chain here and execute after foreach
}
```

So, main question is how to call unlimited and unknown number of class functions with arguments in chain? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your `$array['method_*']` into `{}` brackets:

```
$result = $my_class->{$array['method_1']}($array['method_1'][0], $array['method_1'][0])
    ->{$array['method_1']}($array['method_2'][0], $array['method_2'][0])
    ->{$array['method_n']}($array['method_n'][0], $array['method_n'][0]);
```

If I may notice, although PHP allows this, for code readability and reliability you should rethink about dynamic chain calls. It may save you few lines, but may raise some headaches later debugging

// Appendix:
IMO, better way of doing your logic is via `foreach` and [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
foreach ($array as $method => $args) {
    call_user_func_array(array($my_class, $method), $args);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Will it work in `foreach($array as $function => $args)` ?

Comment: Yes, but ofc with no chaining

Comment: @Orbitum: Sure, just make sure you rename the `$method` variable throughout the loop.

Comment: I've replaced `call_user_func()` with `call_user_func_array()` since the later enables passing unlimited number of arguments - which is more flexible solution

Comment: Ok, it looks nice, but it will call only one method of class. What if I want to build query from many methods and then call it?

Comment: @Orbitum It will call as many methods your `$array` variable contains - completely dynamic and arbitrary number of arguments may be passed to each method called